# Can a self defeating pro attitude make for a meaningful life?

Tags: meaning-of-life, psychoanalysis, love

Can a self defeating pro attitude make for a meaningful life?

I was thinking of "pro attitude" in the sense of when e.g. one "does what one believes to be really important" or one "achieves one’s highly ranked goals". I am living with a seemingly lifelong disability/mental illness, and it might seem that if I were to achieve the goal of recovery, then there is nothing anymore that I have recovered from. But this is a kind of estoteric example.

I think there is something general at work here, cases when something can only work if we do something that invalidates the attempt to get it to work. A bit like a friend that insists you reject them or a hobby predicated on how boring it is.

It seems like quite a common neurotic (I think is the correct word) condition: does it make for meaningless lives?